# Residual plot with ggplot with X-axis as "ranked" residuals

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to re-create a plot like this in ggplot:[image].

This graph takes the residuals from a regression output, and plots them in order (with the X-axis being a rank of residuals).

My best attempt at this was something like the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(modelr)

d <- d %>% add_residuals(mod1, var = "resid")
d$resid_rank <- rank(d$resid)

ggplot(data = d, aes(x = resid_rank, y = resid)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  theme_bw()
```

However, this yields a completely blank graph.  I tried something like this:

```
ggplot(data = d, aes(x = resid_rank, y = resid)) +
  geom_segment(yend = 0, aes(xend=resid)) +
  theme_bw()
```

But this yields the segments that go in the wrong direction.  What is the right way to do this, and to color those lines by a third factor?

FAKE DATASET:

```
library(estimatr)
library(fabricatr)

#simulation
dat <- fabricate(
  N = 10000,
  y =  runif(N, 0, 10),
  x = runif(N, 0, 100)
)

#add an outlier
dat <- rbind(dat, c(300, 5))
dat <- rbind(dat, c(500, 3))

dat$y_log <- log(dat$y)
dat$x_log <- log(dat$x)
dat$y_log_s <- scale(log(dat$y))
dat$x_log_s <- scale(log(dat$x))

mod1 <- lm(y_log ~ x_log, data = dat))
```

Comment: Can you add example data (`dput(d)`)?

Comment: I notice that you create a variable for residuals with the name resid, but then you call rank on d$resid_rank, shouldn't it be rank(d$resid)?

Comment: Good catch.  That was just bad formatting trying to change all the variable names to something generic. @PoGibas, unfortunately the data is proprietary, but I can work on making a simulated dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the build in dataset from the help page on `lm()` to create this example. I also just directly used `resid()` to get the residuals. It's unclear where / why the colored bars would be different, but basically you'd need to add a column to your data.frame that specificies why they are red or blue, then pass that to `fill`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.4.4
#example from lm
ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group <- gl(2, 10, 20, labels = c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight <- c(ctl, trt)
lm.D9 <- lm(weight ~ group)
resids <- data.frame(resid = resid(lm.D9))
#why are some bars red and some blue? No clue - so I'll pick randomly
resids$group <- sample(c("group 1", "group 2"), nrow(resids), replace = TRUE)
#rank
resids$rank <- rank(-1 * resids$resid)


ggplot(resids, aes(rank, resid, fill = group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(-1,1), colour = "darkgray", linetype = 2) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(-2,2), colour = "lightgray", linetype = 1) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("group 1" = "red", "group 2" = "blue"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-01-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Would you have any guess as to why no bars show up when I run this on my real dataset, but points do if I use geom_point() instead of geom_bar()?

Comment: @Parseltongue - unfortunately, no. Or not atleast without looking at the `str()` of your actual data, which sounds like is proprietary. You could start by comparing `str()` of my example and identifying what is different compared to your data. If you set the limits, i.e. `ylim(c(-.1, .1))` you would cut off many of the residuals, but *some* of them should still show up.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! Will see if that helps

Comment: Strangely, it appears the problem is caused by two factors: `scale_fill_manual(values = c("group 1" = "red", "group 2" = "blue"))` will force my data to not render anything.  And because my actual dataset is 255,000 observations, it appears ggplot just won't plot that many datapoints in bar plot form.  Also appears that I need to remove all missing values for xlim to be properly handled

Comment: @Parseltongue - that line is what colors the bars red vs blue...if you don't have a variable named "group" and if the two unique entries in that column are not "group 1" and "group 2", then you will have problems since ggplot is applying the colors red and blue to group 1 and group 2. If you don't have a variable to color by, simply comment out / remove that line. It's not clear what meaning red/blue had in your original post, so I made up something randomly (see code above with `sample()`)